# Terminal command to remove custom icon from file (HFS+)

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, filesystem, hfs+

#### Context

In Mac OS X / macOS you can select a file in the Finder, click Informations then click the icon, and paste any image/icon that is in the clipboard. Now this file has a custom icon made of this image.

To remove it, the usual way is to select the file, click Informations, select the custom icon then hit <kbd>delete</kbd> and it removes the custom icon, restoring the default one.

#### Question

Is there a way to remove these custom icons from these files *without* having to open a Finder window? For example with a Terminal command?

#### Why

A file has a corrupted custom icon, opening the Finder in this folder causes the Finder to beachball and the HDD to freak out. But I still can access the folder content, and this file, from the command line, if I don't first open a Finder window. So I'm thinking that I "just" need to access the metadata differently to remove the custom icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *files* with a custom *icon*, **macOS** writes the *icon data* as a *resource fork* to the *file*.  Use the `xattr` *command* in the following form:

```
xattr -d com.apple.ResourceFork /path/to/filename
```

For more information about the `xattr` *command*, in **Terminal** type the following *command* and press: <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
man xattr
```

Or just type `xattr` and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

---

For *folders* with custom *icon*, in **Terminal**, change directory to the *folder* containing the custom *icon*, e.g.:

```
cd /path/to/foo
```

Once in the *directory*, use the following *command* to remove the custom *icon*:

```
rm Icon?
```

Note that you can also just use:

```
rm /path/to/foo/Icon?
```

However, you cannot use *quotes*, single or double, if the *pathname* has *spaces* and must escape the *spaces* with a *backslash*, `\`, e.g.:

```
rm /path/to/foo\ bar/Icon?
```

Quoting the *pathname* will just return the following error:

```
: No such file or directory
```

By default, `Icon?` is a hidden file and the `?` in `Icon?` is actually a linefeed, `\n`, character.

Comment: Can't other things be stored in the resource fork? If so, wouldn't `xattr -d com.apple.ResourceFork myfile` delete all such assets, including ones that aren't the icon?

Comment: @Tom, In modern versions of **macOS** it's only used in this manner and can be safely deleted for what the OP needed to do. There are other _extended attributes_ that one may not want to delete but they have a different name, e.g. `com.apple.FinderInfo`, `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate:`, `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`, etc.

Comment: You can quote the pathname with spaces. You just need to remove the backslashes. It's either quoting, or escaping with backslashes, not both. `"/some path/with spaces/"` or `/some\ path/with\ spaces/`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `SetFile` to flip the file's "custom icon" bit off:

```
SetFile -a c /path/to/file
```

One difference between this and `xattr -d com.apple.ResourceFork` is the `xattr -d` destroys the image data in the file's resource fork, whereas `SetFile` leaves the data in place. If you leave the data in place, you can restore the custom icon later, like so:

```
SetFile -a C /path/to/file # note the lettercase
```

If you want, you can extract the custom icon into a separate file before removing it completely from the file:

```
DeRez -only icns /path/to/file > extracted.rsrc
```

(Note that this copies the data out. You'd still need to delete the embedded icon using `xattr`.)

I should also note that `xattr -d` leaves the "custom icon" bit set on, meaning that if you ever insert new icns data into the file's resource fork, it will show through immediately. So, I think if you really want to make the file as vanilla as possible, you should do both: delete the fork, *and* unset the custom bit. (But I really don't know if it matters.)

(BTW, you can insert custom icon data like so:)

```
Rez -append icon.rsrc -o /path/to/file
```

Comment: Cool. Is there a way to make the icon remain in place if e.g. a bash script is edited and then saved in a text editor? Is the best solution to first extract the icon, then edit the file, and then insert the icon again after saving?

Comment: @nisc I think editing the file using another app _does not_ remove the custom icon normally. I do this stuff with my IDE's workspace files (which are just JSON files), and it seems like updating my workspace settings (which re-saves the workspace file) does not remove the custom icon. If your save operation rewrites the file from scratch (which some apps do), you may need a multi-step process like you describe.

Comment: K. I've seen this both with `vim` and with `Atom`